# How do I install ql570lpr-1.0.1-0.i386.deb using terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, printing, dpkg

I have tried to install ql570lpr-1.0.1-0.i386.deb using terminal but I'm having difficulties as I'm not sure how to solve the following:

```
paul@Linuxlap:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all ql570lpr-1.0.1-0.i386.deb

[sudo] password for paul: 

(Reading database ... 246988 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack ql570lpr-1.0.1-0.i386.deb ...

Unpacking ql570lpr:i386 (1.0.1) over (1.0.1) ...

Setting up ql570lpr:i386 (1.0.1) ...

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/spool/lpd/ql570’: No such file or 
directory

chown: cannot access ‘/var/spool/lpd/ql570’: No such file or directory

chgrp: cannot access ‘/var/spool/lpd/ql570’: No such file or directory

chmod: cannot access ‘/var/spool/lpd/ql570’: No such file or directory
```

Thanks very much for your help :)

Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"lpd" is not created on a vanilla Ubuntu and some Linux systems do. So start with

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/lpd/
```

The software is likely NOT intended for Ubuntu and depends on a "lpd" directory in "spool" and does not create it itself. That command will create all missing directories (the `-p` does that).

If the problem is the "ql570" you can also do a ...

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/spool/lpd/ql570
```

... but I would assume that one will be created by the installer.

Then repeat the ...

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all ql570lpr-1.0.1-0.i386.deb
```

and it will install.

Are you sure you need a "i386" (ie. a 32-bit version) though?

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, the installer ran perfectly this time.  Those where the only drivers available for my printer from the Brother website. Ubuntu would classed as 'deb' as opposed to 'rpm' when selecting driver types yeah? Printer doesn't work now I've installed the drivers...

Comment: Yes, but not all DEBs are for every Ubuntu, You probably also need to do some manual work to get the driver working with lpd.

Comment: Oh have a look here http://www.panticz.de/ubuntu_brother_ql-500 It also has the mkdir in there ;-) That looks like it should work

Comment: Cool, thanks man. I'll take a look at the link a little later, website seems to be down...